# Is "…sitting direction to windows…" correct?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Did I write the following sentence correctly?

> In my office, I'm the only person who has sitting direction to windows, whereas the other staff turn their back to the windows.

I don't want to repeat "window" two times like this, so is there any word I can use here?
Do the native speakers say like that?

Thank you for helping me learning English.

Comment: In my office, I’m the only one who sits facing the windows; everyone else sits with their backs to them.

Comment: thank you @Jim. :) But could you explain to me why we use "facing" here? Is it a special grammar structure?

Comment: oh, I have searched for the answer in Oxford Dictionary, and they explain that "sit doing something". So, basically i guest i understand why we use "facing" here. :)

Comment: "facing" here could be replaced by "in the direction of"--that's its meaning in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'it' (or rather as suggested, the plural form 'them') would be able to replace 'the windows' in that sentence. But overall, I'd say it differently. Using most of your words, perhaps like so,

> In my office, only I sit facing the window, whereas the other staff
>   have their back to it

P.S. I've been trying to learn Vietnamese recently and your sentence structure sounds a lot like a translation from tieng Viet to tieng Anh. But, may be its just me.

Comment: oh, thank you for your correction. Actually I'm still struggling learning English. My problem is I often translate word to word when i want to say something in English. :))

Comment: +1 the OP uses the term *windows*, so I'd also mention substituting the second plural form with "them"

Comment: thank you @Mari-LouA . I'll learn from this mistake. Please feel free to correct my English.